# Is this network identity issue? VM cloning goofup?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

An existing Vmware VM (x.x.x.1) was cloned ,

i.e xxx1 ->  xxx2

OS: Win Server 2012

1. I'm able to RDP to both xxx1 and xxx2 (At RDP level looks like both nodes/device/ip are not confused?)
2. ipconfig /all -- shows unique host names, unique Physical/MAC, unique ipv4 - in xxx1 & xxx2
3. tracert -- times out, some security/firewall config.
4. When I send SoapUI request to xxx1, it gets to xxx1 (expected)

Problem:

1. When I send a soap request to xxx2-cloned-VM), xxx1-the-parent receives the message (can see in application logs). Which is **not desirable**.

How to diagnose and find where the problem is? 
What VM config should I check?

- The VM guys are very protective of their turff :-), they said some config change in IIS has rectified the issue. I do not feel it was true, I felt since request to one VM1 is ending up in another VM2, it must be some network identity problem.

Comment: Do you use a `hosts` file for these VMs?

Comment: What are we talking about here? Presumably not ESXi... but Workstation / Player? How are the networks configured (NAT / Bridge)?

Comment: Are "_xxx1_" and "_xxx1 (parent which is not a cloned machine)_" two different systems? Either way, please clarify...